# Opening only one instance of url using window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net web page which has a hyperlink. when ever that hyperlink is clicked, a new browser window is opened using javascript `window.open`. I want that If user clicks this link multiple times, then only one window is opened and not multiple windows. I just want that window to be highlighted when user clicks that hyperlink multiple times. Do I need to use `window.open` to detect if the url is opened in any other tab of the  browser ? Is there any jQuery plugin built in for this so that I can use it  for browser compatibility.

Here is the hyperlink url:

```
<a onclick="addClick()" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    New</a>
```

and here is the code I am using:

```
function addClick() {
    var ID = jQuery("#ID").val();
    var PSSWD = jQuery("#PSSWD").val();
    var ACCID = jQuery("#ACCID").val();
    var PASSWDINT = jQuery("#PASSWDINT").val();

    window.open("LoginAPI?ID=" + encodeURIComponent(ID) + "&PSSWD=" + encodeURIComponent(PSSWD) + "&ACCID=" + encodeURIComponent(ACCID) + "&PASSWDINT=" + encodeURIComponent(PASSWDINT) + "", "LoginAPI");
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Can't you just have a javascript call on button click and set a variable the first time it is clicked? Then if the variable is set, don't open a new window..

Comment: Hi I think you can use `window.showModalDialog` instead of `window.open`

Comment: What code are you using to `window.open`

Comment: I am using  window.open("LoginAPI?ID=" + encodeURIComponent(ID) + "&PSSWD=" + encodeURIComponent(PSSWD) + "&ACCID=" + encodeURIComponent(ACCID) + "&PASSWDINT=" + encodeURIComponent(PASSWDINT) + "", "LoginAPI");

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
window.open("<url>", "<window name>");
```

This should always open in the same window. See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open).

Comment: This will reload the content (which may or may not be desired behavior).

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Not if you use the same name for the window name argument it doesn't: http://jsbin.com/omider/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/omider/1/edit).

Comment: This code works for me in Chrome, IE and FF: `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://localhost', 'myWin'); return false;">Open</a>`. IE & FF don't activate the window unfortunately, but Chrome does.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com" onclick="openwindow.call(this); return false;">open window</a>

var wins = {};
function openwindow(){
    var url = this.href;
    if(typeof wins[url] === 'undefined' || wins[url].closed)
        wins[url] = window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: +1 Would be even better to get the `href` from the link, so the link is real, can be prefetched, etc., etc.: `<a href="/the/real/link" onclick="openwindow(this.href); return false;">open window</a>`

Comment: There's no reason to use `getAttribute` for this. `href` has been a reflected property on anchors since the mid-90's at least. Also note that you've left the `url` argument in your function.

Comment: @karaxuna : url is not passrd as parameter to link. link uses a function playapi() without parameter. and here is the url created in that function: I am using window.open("LoginAPI?ID=" + encodeURIComponent(ID) + "&PSSWD=" + encodeURIComponent(PSSWD) + "&ACCID=" + encodeURIComponent(ACCID) + "&PASSWDINT=" + encodeURIComponent(PASSWDINT) + "", "LoginAPI");

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: That information really should have been in the question from the start.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Looking at the updated question, the answer above still applies. All that changes is where you get the URL from.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder does not work on fiddle :( can you tell me why? http://jsfiddle.net/6qEPX/1/ . unload is called after new tab is opened

Comment: @karaxuna: I'm afraid I can't, no. I ran into this a while back but never figured it out. It could be that the initial `about:blank` is being unloaded to make room for the actual page, I don't know. I ended up implementing a call back to `window.opener` when closed to deregister the window.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated answer and it works http://jsfiddle.net/6qEPX/2/ . thanks to @Shekhar for `closed` property

Answer (score 0):

To open only one instance of a popup window in an HTML page, use the `windowName` parameter of the `window.open method`. 
For example

```
window.open('http://www.abc.com')
```

will open a new window each time the user clicks the link containing the window.open code. 
In constrast,

```
window.open('http://www.abc.com','abc')
```

will open only one instance of the window, no matter how many times users click the link.

you can also use `focus` function as used below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}

      if (!newwindow.closed) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>
```

### Edit 1

```
<a onclick="return addClick()" href="javascript:void(0)">New</a>
```

and here is the code I am using:

```
function addClick() {
    var ID = jQuery("#ID").val();
    var PSSWD = jQuery("#PSSWD").val();
    var ACCID = jQuery("#ACCID").val();
    var PASSWDINT = jQuery("#PASSWDINT").val();

    window.open("LoginAPI?ID=" + encodeURIComponent(ID) + "&PSSWD=" + encodeURIComponent(PSSWD) + "&ACCID=" + encodeURIComponent(ACCID) + "&PASSWDINT=" + encodeURIComponent(PASSWDINT) + "", "LoginAPI");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Shejhar: I am using window name but still it opens new tab. I have updated question with code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>


var windowObjectReference = null; // global variable

function openFFPromotionPopup() {
  if(windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed)
  /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
     or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */

  {
    windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.spreadfirefox.com/",
   "PromoteFirefoxWindowName", "resizable,scrollbars,status");
    /* then create it. The new window will be created and
       will be brought on top of any other window. */
  }
  else
  {
    windowObjectReference.focus();
    /* else the window reference must exist and the window
       is not closed; therefore, we can bring it back on top of any other
       window with the focus() method. There would be no need to re-create
       the window or to reload the referenced resource. */
  };
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openFFPromotionPopup()">click here</a>
```

Check the reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open